# Limitar tiempo de sesión

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda para limitar el tiempo de inactividad en HTML y PHP.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
inicio-php<br>
session_start();<br>
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
{<br>
?>
   <p>Aqui va mi codigo HTML</p>
inicio-php<br>
}else{<br>
 echo '<script>location.href = "index.php";</script>';<br>
}<br>
```

Comment: En HTML usando javascript, particularmente el **setTimeout** allí colocas código que luego de "n" tiempo rediccione a página donde se cierre la sesión abierta y desde luego finalmente a la pantalla de logeo/autenticación.

Comment: Puedes darme un ejemplo Cómo ayuda te lo agradeceria

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tengo un código que uso para destruir la sesión tras pasar cierto tiempo.
Este código lo implementas en tu fichero global.

```
<?php
session_start();

// Máxima duración de sesión activa en hora
define( 'MAX_SESSION_TIEMPO', 3600 * 1 );

// Controla cuando se ha creado y cuando tiempo ha recorrido 
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'ULTIMA_ACTIVIDAD' ] ) && 
     ( time() - $_SESSION[ 'ULTIMA_ACTIVIDAD' ] > MAX_SESSION_TIEMPO ) ) {

    // Si ha pasado el tiempo sobre el limite destruye la session
    destruir_session();
}

$_SESSION[ 'ULTIMA_ACTIVIDAD' ] = time();

// Función para destruir y resetear los parámetros de sesión
function destruir_session() {

    $_SESSION = array();
    if ( ini_get( 'session.use_cookies' ) ) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(
            session_name(),
            '',
            time() - MAX_SESSION_TIEMPO,
            $params[ 'path' ],
            $params[ 'domain' ],
            $params[ 'secure' ],
            $params[ 'httponly' ] );
    }

    @session_destroy();
}
```

En cuando el usuario haya iniciado sesión y quiera acceder en un fichero que necesita ser autentificado:

```
<?php 
require_once 'fichero-global.php';    

if ( isset( $_SESSION['usuario'] ) ) {

   // Sesión activa
}
else{

   // Sesión inactiva  
   header('Location: /');
}
```

El fichero global con el código de control de sesión se renueva cada vez en cuando el usuario hace una actividad en el mismo fichero, en el caso contrario cuando pasa el tiempo establecido se destruye la sesión y debería iniciarlo de nuevo.

Comment: Y si es por minutos

Comment: @ErickPaulLozadaPeñarreta - Haz los cálculos: 1 minuto tiene 60 segundos: `define( 'MAX_SESSION_TIEMPO', 60 * 5 ); // === 5 minutos` 1 hora tiene 60 minutos:  `define( 'MAX_SESSION_TIEMPO', 60 * 60 * 5 ); // === 5 horas` (60 * 60 === 3600)

Comment: Ok, el codigo esta bien y se adapta a mi sistema gracias; tambien desearia que se cierre la sesion automaticamente ya sabes

Comment: @ErickPaulLozadaPeñarreta - No... no se a que té refieres... además está página no es para pedir tareas... si tienes un problema más aparte de la pregunta original deberías hacer un nuevo post y aceptar la respuesta a cual más te era útil para cerrar el tema...saludos

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día.**

Lo básico de tu HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
   /* title, meta, link, style.... */
   <script>
     /*
       A continuación se asume lo siguiente:
         - La rutas son ilustrativas y relativas; son sugerencias a tu sitio
         - El nombre del PHP es significativo a lo que se debe hacer.
         - El tiempo se reinicia cada vez que se vuelve a cargar la página.
         - Puedes implementarlo más a fondo usando eventos keypress, mousemove o cualquiera 
           que indique el usuario este haciendo algo a fin de reiniciar el tiempo.
     */

     /* 
       En la raíz de tu sitio existe carpeta "Login" con archivo "cerrarSesion.php", 
       en este archivo tienes las instrucciones para cerrar sesión (finalizar todo lo que 
       a la sesión corresponda) y al finalizarse redireccionas a la pantalla de 
       logeo/autenticación */
      var cierraSesionIrLogeo = "/Login/cerrarSesion.php"; 
      /* 
        Cada mil es un segundo; 60000=1 minuto; aqui coloca el tiempo de espera antes 
        de cerar la sesión; esto se inicializara cada vez que se carge la página */
      setTimeout(function(){ windows.location=cierraSesionIrLogeo; }, 60000); 
      /*
         Claro esta que conforme la estructura/patrón de diseño que estes usando será 
         donde lo colocaras a fin que se repita/coloques en todas las páginas donde
         quieras forzar el cierre de sesión.
      */
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Todo lo que compone el cuerpo de tu página -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad o te de idea de que hacer.

Esta es una implementación simple; la verdad de momento no me a tocado sistemas con tal comportamiento, por lo regular me piden que la sesión dure lo más que se pueda abierta (responsabilidad del usuario cerrarla explícitamente ) :D

Answer (score 0):

Este problema se podría resolver programando un método como el siguiente. (Se verifica la IP y el puerto):

```
public static function UsuarioIngresoOK()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["IdUsuario"]) && $_SESSION["IdUsuario"] != NULL && $_SESSION["ConectadoDesdeIP"] == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] && $_SESSION["ConectadoDesdePuerto"] == $_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
} // public static function UsuarioIngresoOK()
```

Si no funciona con el IP y el puerto, también se puede hacer funcionar más o menos de la siguiente forma... (Se establece un tiempo máximo en este caso de 5 minutos, que es igual a 5*60 segundos).

```
public static function UsuarioIngresoOK()
{
    define("MAX_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO_SEGUNDOS_DESDE_ULTIMO_USO_SESION", 5*60); // Se fija el máximo tiempo transcurrido en 5 minutos

    if (isset($_SESSION["IdUsuario"]) && $_SESSION["IdUsuario"] != NULL && self::TiempoTranscurridoSegundosDesdeUltimoUsoSesion() <= MAX_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO_SEGUNDOS_DESDE_ULTIMO_USO_SESION)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
} // public static function UsuarioIngresoOK()

private static function TiempoTranscurridoSegundosDesdeUltimoUsoSesion()
{
    $TiempoTranscurridoSegundos = time() - $_SESSION["HoraSegundosUltimoUsoSesion"];
    $_SESSION["HoraSegundosUltimoUsoSesion"] = time();
    return $TiempoTranscurridoSegundos;
} // private static function TiempoTranscurridoSegundosDesdeUltimoUsoSesion()
```